# Ubuntu Print Server in Windows Environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, printing, cups

For my project at work, I decided to create a Ubuntu Linux 16.04 print server but it's in a Windows environment. I installed CUPS via apt and Samba via apt also. The few printers I have setup work fine, they share and everything to either my Linux computer at work or any Windows computer. There's only one caveat. When I try to install a printer on Windows, a prompt comes up saying "No driver found!" and I have to manually install each and every single driver. Is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: Yes, preinstall the drivers using GPO.

Comment: @JohnKeates - How would I go about doing that? A link to a step-by-step instruction webpage would be beneficial.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754699(v=ws.11).aspx